# How do I reset my root password on Chromebook?

Tags: password, root, chrome-book

I am very new to Linux and I'm not super computer savvy so that's sort of why I don't really know what I'm doing. I try to reset my `root` password in a Chromebook.

As far as I know, I need to boot to the GRUB menu but I cannot figure out how to do that. I'll try to answer whatever questions I need to but just remember I'm sort of new to all of this.

What I have tried so far is rebooting my Chromebook (holding the refresh button+the power button), and holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, which as far as I know is supposed to open up the GRUB menu. It didn't really even reboot, I believe it just shut down, so I guess the reboot itself didn't work, and in that case, I'm not sure how to do that either since there doesn't seem to be an option for it (if what I did already didn't work).

Comment: It'd help to know what you already researched and tried on your own, so we don't suggest the same things. [Please edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/677691/edit) your question to include this.

Comment: Sorry about that; fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've using Linux for 2 years. I have never used Chromebook. I believe you know how to use terminal. So fire up a terminal and type the following

If you know your root password, login into root.To do that Execute the following

`su`

This will prompt something like this

`Enter password`

Enter password, now you will be a root user. Then execute

`passwd`

This will prompt you to enter a new password.

If you forgot the root password, just type

`sudo passwd`

This will ask you for your user password. Enter it, now you will be prompted to enter a new password, this will change your **root** password. Lemme know if it worked. Good day !

Comment: It seems to have worked, thank you so much!